# Jest testing errors after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: javascript, jestjs, macos-big-sur, jest-puppeteer

After upgrading to Big Sur, some of my jest tests throws [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvDV3.png). It also spams the console with

`Chromium[29916:572689] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x7ffe74b9ac90>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.`

and

`[.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : DoEndSharedImageAccessCHROMIUM: bound texture is not a shared image`

Ultimately stopping the testing with `sysctlbyname kern.nx: No such file or directory`

I've already done `brew upgrade` after upgrading to Big Sur, but it has not fixed these errors.